# Query parameter using superagent

Tags: node.js, superagent

I'm creating a small Node.js application which calls some REST api´s using Superagent (v5.1.2). I need to send a filter option with a get request.

The API endpoint needs the following structure:

*endpoint-url/test?filter=_name eq 'testname'*

I´m struggling to achieve this result using superagent with the built-in query method. When I send the request I´ll get all items returned, so the filter option isn't making any effect. Once I test it via postman I´ll get just the specified item returned with the `_name = 'testname'`.

Here is my code snippet

```
let name = 'testname';
superagent.get('endpoint-url/test')
           .authBearer(token)
           .query({'filter': '_name eq ' + name})
           .then(res => {
               ...
           })
           .catch(err => {
               ...
           });
```

Comment: filer or filter ? ar you sure?

Comment: it´s filter thank you. I´ve edited the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example:

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const memoryDB = {
  users: [{ name: "testname" }, { name: "haha" }],
};

app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query);
  const filterName = req.query.filter.split("eq")[1].trim();
  const user = memoryDB.users.find((user) => user.name === filterName);
  res.status(200).json(user);
});

module.exports = app;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const app = require("./app");
const superagent = require("superagent");
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("59246379", () => {
  let server;
  before((done) => {
    server = app.listen(3003, () => {
      console.info(`HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:${server.address().port}`);
      done();
    });
  });

  after((done) => {
    server.close(done);
  });
  it("should pass", () => {
    let name = "testname";
    return superagent
      .get("http://localhost:3003/test")
      .query({ filter: "_name eq " + name })
      .then((res) => {
        expect(res.status).to.be.equal(200);
        expect(res.body).to.be.eql({ name: "testname" });
      });
  });
});
```

Integration test result with coverage report:

```sh
  59246379
HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:3003
{ filter: '_name eq testname' }
    ✓ should pass (46ms)


  1 passing (57ms)

-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File         |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files    |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.test.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59246379

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and time. I´ve sorted it out!